# Collision Check not working

Tags: c

```
char* matrix [10][10];  //matrix to put words in (all elements are equal to 1 at this point)
char words[20][20]= {
    " c a t "," c a r "," b e a r ",
    " s h i p "," m o u s e "," b e a t l e ",
    " c o a t "," n e s t "," i c e "," s u g a r ",
    " b a c o n "," f r o w n "," s m i l e "," d e a d ",
    " f e a t h e r "," g o a t "," h e n "," j e l l y ",
    " k o a l a "," l i p s "
}; // 4 of these words will be randomly chosen

for( i=0;i<4;i++){
    d=0;
    do{
        random = (rand()%20);
        list[i]=words[random];
        d=0;
        for( j=0;j<i;j++){
            if(strcmp(words[random],list[j])==0)d=1;
        }
    }while(d);//making sure there are no duplicate words

    strcpy(temp, words[random] );
    length=strlen(temp); //length of word
    printf("temp:%s",words[random]);
    ans=(length/2);// length divided by 2 to remove spaces
    size=(9-ans);// number of columns-word length

    emptyD=0;   
    do{
        x=(rand()%10);//generates a random co-ordinate
        emptyD=0;
        for(k=0;k<ans;k++){// for loop starting from zero till the length of word
            if(strcmp(matrix[x+k][x+k],"1")==0)
             emptyD=1; //checks whether the matrix element is equal to 1 
        }
    } while(emptyD || x>size);
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do here is fill a matrix with words
placed diagonally. to avoid collision with other words I set the whole
matrix to 1 beforehand. every time a character is entered the program
checks if the element space is equal to 1 (meaning it is an empty
pos). however this code is not working properly and there are still
collisions. I would appreciate any help :) thanks

Comment: Please share more code for the values of `ans` and `size` and `matrix` as well

Comment: well basically the words are also randomly generated. ans is the word length of the randomly generated word which is working properly. while size is the (number of columns)- (word length) --> ensuring that the word fits in the matrix :) @nullpointer

Comment: both variables were tested and are working properly :-) @nullpointer

Comment: matrix is a [10][10] char array filled with "1" @nullpointer

Comment: where are you setting `matrix` 's value?

Comment: moreover for `x=9 && k>1` you would end up accessing out of array bounds

Comment: the do while loop checks for out of bounds ! with size
since size=(9-ans); //where ans is word length @nullpointer

Comment: what is the value of `ans` for 'chri'? Is it 4? then in that case x could be 9 and in your for loop at some point of time k would be 2. Can you see it now?

Comment: yes i understand ! how do i fix this error ? thanks alot

Comment: can we have all variable initializations and better input output in the question to figure out what actually would fix your problem. :)

Comment: This seems absurd at first  `list[i]=words[random]` , what is `list[i`]? and `word[20][20]` is a 2D array,isn't it?

Comment: no that works. that basically puts the chosen word in another 1d array. used to check for duplicate words

Comment: depending on what your `list` is...as said at first,share meaningful and complete code to explain

Answer (score 1):

Out of all the possibilities that you might be facing because of the values assigned to `ans` and `size`. I believe `matrix[10][10]` is what is causing the problem since for `x=9` and any `k>1` you would end up accessing out of array bounds.

You may want to `break` the `for(k=0;k<ans;k++)` loop after the comparison and assigning `emptyD=1;` . But for sure need to keep a check in accessing the array indexes.

Or something like this should help

```
//no  for loop required
if(strcmp(matrix[x][x],"1")==0) {
  emptyD=1; //checks whether the matrix element is equal to 1 
}
```

for which I am not sure what would end the while loop, since you know the values better and they are tested :)

Comment: how do i break the for loop without terminating the whole prog tho?

Comment: @chri  You can use `if(strcmp(matrix[x][x],"1")==0) {
  emptyD=1; break; 
}` but that doesn't make sense since if `matrix[9+0][9+0]` and `matrix[9+1][9+1]` wouldn't be equal to `1` it would again reach to `matrix[9+2][9+2]`

Comment: but how will it display the whole word if it just inputs one character?

Comment: can we have all variable initializations and better input output in the question to figure out what actually would fix your problem. :)